# Add File listing loop to table using runSQL with variables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Having trouble getting this to work.

I am looping through a dialog generated file list and inserting into a table. I can not get the variable to work right. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.

```
Dim SQLCode As String
Dim varFile As Variant

Access.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("ClearFileList")

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(1)
With fDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select One or More Files"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Lineviewer Files", "*.CSV"

    If .show = True Then
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
            SQLCode = "INSERT INTO Filelist ([FileName]) VALUES (" & varFile & ");"
            Access.DoCmd.RunSQL SQLCode

        Next
    End If
End With
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `[FileName]` and the file name variable `varFile` should both be text data type.  So Add quotes around the value of `varFile` when you build the SQL statement.  That way the db engine will recognize that value as text.

```
SQLCode = "INSERT INTO Filelist ([FileName]) VALUES ('" & varFile & "');"
```

As a side point, you don't need to build and execute an `INSERT` statement for each of the selected files.  You can open the destination table as a DAO recordset with the `dbAppendOnly` option.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Filelist", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)
```

Then add a row for each selected item.

```vb
For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
    rs.AddNew
    rs!FileName = varFile 
    rs.Update
Next
```

That approach could be faster, though it's doubtful you would actually notice the difference.  But it neatly avoids quoting the selected items, and will accommodate file path names greater than 255 characters if your `FileName` is memo data type.

Comment: I had just tried """ """ and it worked. '" "' is better, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  I revised the answer to include the approach I would use.  See what you think.